# Simple list based output instead of style and javascript ridden ASP.net webforms menu

Tags: asp.net, webforms, menu, cssadapter

Is there a way (or component i could use) to output a simple menu.
I just need it output as a list, like you would use for a simple superfish menu.

I've looked at the menu control and cssadapters (css friendly) which kind of works,
except there is a lot of styles and javascript  output with the menu which is destroying the look.

If I can't find something that outputs a clean list, my next option is to craft some jquery to delete these styles. This is not my preferred option. If you have  a better idea, please let me know.

Just something that looks like this:

```
<ul> Main Menu
 <li> hi </li>
 <li> second menu
    <ul> 
        <li> <a href="hi.aspx"> in second menu </a></li>
        <li> <a href="rabbits.aspx"> hi there </a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Repeater server control.  You are in control of all of the markup output to the screen.

Comment: This is what I have done. Although, because my menu will have multiple levels in the future, I will probably have to make a component or web control that will do this. The repeater won't cut it forever. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: place a repeater inside of a repeater - :)